# Comparing a hashed password to user input in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

I am using asp.net core razor engine.  I have a hash for a password that is saved into my db.  How do I compare that to when the user enters their password.

Here is the method where I hashed the password.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Register(Home model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            PasswordHasher<Home> Hasher = new PasswordHasher<Home>();
            model.Password = Hasher.HashPassword(model, model.Password);
            userFactory.Add(model);
            TempData["message"] = false;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The app retrieved the users password based on the email they give when they register.  What I cannot figure out is how to compare the hashed password to the password the user gives.

Comment: Well you have to hash the password the user inputted and compare this result with the one in the database.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, how do I hash the user inputed password or unhash the password from the db?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to unhash user password. You'll use the same method that you used to hash the db password to hash the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your password hasher need the model type and the model itself as inputs?  What you want to do is use a hasher that *always* returns the same result given the same password input (or, these days, given the same two inputs: a password and a randomly generated SALT that you store alongside the password)

Here's how to do it properly: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

In other words, throw away your current hasher and make one that just takes the password (and ideally salt) as an input.  You hash a newly created password with the exact same lines of code as you hash a "logging in" password - then you compare the logging-in hash to the stored hash, to see if they match.